# How to use Google APIs with Go in Bazel

Tags: go, google-api, bazel

I am currently trying to consume Google APIs (for now only due to the annotation options) in Go from Bazel.

There is the [official repo](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis) for the proto API. There they redirect Go users to [special go variant](https://github.com/google/go-genproto).

Both have only a stub Bazel package defined. Thus none seems to be directly usable.

So one way to do this would be to fork [the latter](https://github.com/google/go-genproto), introduce Packages to build `go_proto_libraries` and hope that the directory structure appeases the [go rules](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go).
Questions:

1. Is there already another repository, which can be used simply?

If not:

2. The latter repo is marked as experimental. How likely are changes?
3. Is the latter repo kept in sync?
4. Should the sources in the latter repo be used or new ones built with Bazel from scratch?
5. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the go team and the answer was:

> https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/proto/go_proto_library.bzl does not have a good solution for this case where the .proto is in a  completely different location from the .pb.go files other than using a genrule to copy the .proto file from its source and then a go_proto_library to operate on it.
>
> https://github.com/pubref/rules_protobuf/blob/master/go/rules.bzl has a go_proto_library that allows the .proto from one place and the .pb.go from another, but disclaimer: this code is not owned or maintained by Google.
>
> As to the questions:
>
> 1) No
>
> 2) No idea
>
> 3) See 2
>
> 4) bazel always recommends generating from the source (in this case the .proto files)
>
> 5) Not yet